# How to check if a nested list contain only empty strings

Tags: python, python-2.7, nested-lists

In pyqt I have a qtableview which a user can edit. If the users makes a change to the table, the table will be copied when the user is done. If no changes are made, the table is skipped. The table is filled with empty strings i.e:

```
table = [["","",""],["","",""]]
```

I want to check if the table contains only `""`, and if it does, ignore it. If it doesnt, i.e. contains a `"1"`, some code runs on the list.
Now I have a working code but its not very pythonic and I wonder how I can improve it. My code is as follows:

```
tabell1 = [["","",""],["","",""]]
meh = 0
for item in self.tabell1:
    for item1 in item:
        if item1 == "":
            pass
        else:
            meh = 1
if meh == 1:
    do the thing
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To check if any element in any of the sublist fulfills the condition you could use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#any) and a nested generator expression:

```
tabell1 = [["","",""],["","",""]]
if any(item for sublist in tabell1 for item in sublist):
    # do the thing
```

This also has the advantage that it stops as soon as it finds one not-empty string! Your method would continue to search until it checked all items in all sublists.

Empty strings are considered `False` and every string containing at least one item is considered `True`. However you could also explicitly compare to empty strings:

```
tabell1 = [["","",""],["","",""]]
if any(item != "" for sublist in tabell1 for item in sublist):
    # do the thing
```

Answer (score 1):

The primary thing I see that could be more pythonic is using the fact that empty strings are considered false, something like this...

```
tabell1 = [["","",""],["","",""]]
meh = 0
for sublist in self.tabell1:
    if any(sublist):  # true if any element of sublist is not empty
        meh = 1
        break         # no need to keep checking, since we found something
if meh == 1:
    do the thing
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could avoid looping through the list by converting it to a string, removing all the characters that would only appear if it were empty, then checking if it is empty or not:

```
tabell1 = [["","",""],["","",""]]
if not str(tabell1).translate(None, "[]\"\', "):
    #do the thing
```

Although this will mean that any tables containing only instances of `[`, `]`, `"`, `'`, and  will be considered empty.